# PHP parse_str function replaces + sign with a space

Tags: php

I have a variable I am passing through url as a `jSON` string, a part of which is the below string:

```
signature=8W2sp\/J+kC6fh8a88jabNPuA8048sShDnXNOo1jSQ=
```

When I read the url and parse the string using `parse_str()` function in php the `+` sign is getting replaced by a space. Is there a way to disable replacing the `+` by space.

Comment: use `urlencode` inside `parse_str()` or replace `+` with `%2B` before parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [parse_str](https://secure.php.net/parse_str) automatically applies [url_decode](https://secure.php.net/urldecode) to the given string, plus symbols are decoded to a space character.

To keep plus sign, replace the `+` with its encoded counterpart `%2B`.

```php
$array = [];
$input = "signature=8W2sp\/J+kC6fh8a88jabNPuA8048sShDnXNOo1jSQ=";
parse_str(str_replace('+', '%2B', $input), $array);
var_dump($array['signature']);
```

Comment: I tried this, but parse_str is actually putting a *string* in $arr.

Comment: It does not work for the key-value string as OP asked, your answer is returning single object array with the whole string. like Array
(
    [signature=8W2sp\/J+kC6fh8a88jabNPuA8048sShDnXNOo1jSQ=] => 
)

Comment: You are right, @VishalSolanki. I've updated the answer. Thanks a lot.