# Facing issue with parse_str(), Replacing + char to space

Tags: php, regex, urlencode

I have the following string url:

> HostName=MyHostName;SharedAccessKeyName=SOMETHING;SharedAccessKey=VALUE+VALUE=

I need to extract the key-value pair in an array. I have used `parse_str()` in PHP below is my code:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$str = "HostName=MyHostName&SharedAccessKeyName=SOMETHING&SharedAccessKey=VALUE+VALUE=";
parse_str($str,$arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

output:

```
array (
  'HostName' => 'MyHostName',
  'SharedAccessKeyName' => 'SOMETHING',
  'SharedAccessKey' => 'VALUE VALUE=',
)
```

you can see in the `SharedAccessKey` char `+` is replaced by `space` for this issue, I referred the [Similiar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094261/php-parse-str-function-replaces-sign-with-a-space), Marked answer is not the correct one according to the OP scenario, This says that first do `urlencode()` and then pass it because `parse_str()` first decode URL then separate the key-values but this will return array object  of a single array which return the whole string as it is like for my case its output is like:

```
Array
(
    [HostName=MyHostName&SharedAccessKeyName=SOMETHING&SharedAccessKey=VALUE+VALUE=] => 
)
```

Please help me out, not for only `+` char rather for all the characters should come same as they by the `parse_str()`

Comment: If you want to `urlencode`, you could use something like `array_map(function ($x) {return urlencode($x);}, $arr);`. Else, why not just `str_replace` spaces with `+`s?

Comment: I don't need `urlencode` and if i do `str_replace` for space with `+`, And if a similar character like `+` also comes in the string then how can i find that ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the trailing `=` on the last value, is that supposed to be part of the value?

Comment: yes @Nick this is the part of my value of `SharedAccessKey` key it can contain any character

Comment: [`str_replace` is fine](https://3v4l.org/vb0jQ) here

Comment: yes `str_replace` i have the option but @Nick answer looks fine

Comment: Down Vote why? please also explain the reason, It would be good for me, This kind of thing is not fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try emulating `parse_str` with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\G)(\w+)=([^&]+)(?:&|$)/', $str, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [HostName] => MyHostName
    [SharedAccessKeyName] => SOMETHING
    [SharedAccessKey] => VALUE+VALUE= 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qaOgq)

Comment: @BunkerBoy the only restrictions it places are that the key name is made up of alphanumeric characters or `_`, and the value cannot contain `&`. The first restriction can be eased to match anything other than an `=` by replacing `(\w+)` with `([^=]+)`

Comment: Yes @Nick i have tested your regex, it worked like a charm for me thanks (y)